# Implementing and testing Facebook Social Plugins locally

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

I'm new to Facebook development and would like to to add a comments plugin to my site.
I have created an app on Facebook in case it is needed. but since I have not registered my domain yet, I left the `App Domain` section empty.
Then I copied the code given to me at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ to test the plugin. But when I tested the code in an html file, nothing shows up.

- Do I need an appid to use the comments plugin?
- If I need the appid, should I first buy a domain and add it in the `App Domain` section? can I just test the plugin with `example.com` url?
- In general, what is the most basic way to get comments plugin to work?

UPDATE: 
Based on Lix's answer, I have edited my hosts file and added:

```
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 http://www.example.com
127.0.0.1 http://example.com
```

Here's my test page:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Web page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
</html>
```

But still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far as I know, you *do* need an App to use the Comments plugin (for the moderation functionality I believe). If you look at the [code Facebook generates](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) for the Comments Box, you can see it has an App Id:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID"; // <-- here
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

To get your app working correctly locally though, you will need to set up a virtual host. I usually set them up with names like `http://website1.dev`.

*Part* of setting up a virtual host, as Lix mentions, is adding the domain to your `hosts` file to resolve to your localhost (127.0.0.1).

*Another* part of that is creating a Virtual Host on your local web server for your website. This way you are actually accessing your local site in the browser as `http://example.com` and not `localhost/example.com`. There are lots of good articles about how to set up Apache to do this, here are two:

- http://www.dangrossman.info/2007/08/25/multiple-local-websites-with-apache-in-windows/
- http://mezzoblue.com/archives/2004/08/05/virtual_host/

Then, make sure that your Facebook app's admin settings are set up correctly to allow the `http://example.com` domain. When you set up the Apps "Website" you have to specify the "Site URL". You can also add your new local domain as the apps "App Domain".

God luck!

Comment: So the app id is required for administration purposes. Thanks for the insightful answer :)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is edit your hosts file to contain your "fake" local domain and place that value there.

Comment: would you please elaborate a bit. (I know about hosts file. But I couldn't get what you mean)

Comment: Is it possible to just test it with example.com? just as they did so on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ ?

Comment: sure it is.  All you have to do make your local computer think that example.com exists. Point it to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Still no luck. Updated my question.

Comment: Was a silly fault on my side. renamed js.src = `"//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";` to `js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";` Since I was opening html locally.